# como extraer resultados de laboratorios dentro de un dataframe en python?

Tags: python, pandas

Para una cantidad de 500 mil exámenes de laboratorio **hemogramas** necesito extraer la  hemoglobina de cada laboratorio que se encuentra entre todo el resultado del hemograma ejemplo **HEMOGLOBINA Resul: 13.5 Unid: g/dl**    se extrae solo el = **13.5** gracias por su ayuda.

```
import io
import pandas as pd
        
data = io.StringIO("""
                   ID_PACIENTE;FECHA_EXAMEN;RESULTADO
                   12311545;20/04/2021;RECUENTO LEUCOCITOS Resul: 11.76 Unid: 10^3/uL Refe: 3.98-10.04  ALARMA NEUTROFILOS Resul: 9.29 Unid: 10^3/uL Refe: 1.56-6.13  ALARMA LINFOCITOS. Resul: 1.50 Unid: 10^3/uL Refe: 1.18-3.74   MONOCITOS. Resul: 0.84 Unid: 10^3/uL Refe: 0.24-0.36  ALARMA EOSINOFILOS Resul: 0.02 Unid: 10^3/uL Refe: 0.04-0.36  ALARMA BASOFILOS. Resul: 0.02 Unid: 10^3/uL Refe: 0.01-0.08   NEUTROFILOS %. Resul: 78.9 Unid: % Refe: 34-71.1  ALARMA LINFOCITOS %. Resul: 12.8 Unid: % Refe: 19.3-51.7  ALARMA MONOCITOS %. Resul: 7.1 Unid: % Refe: 4.7-12.5   EOSINOFILOS %. Resul: 0.2 Unid: % Refe: 0.7-5.8  ALARMA BASOFILOS% Resul: 0.2 Unid: % Refe: 0.1-1.2   RECUENTO TOTAL DE GLOBULOS ROJOS Resul: 4.38 Unid: 10^6/uL Refe: 3.93-5.22   HEMOGLOBINA Resul: 11.1 Unid: g/dl Refe: 11.2-15.7  ALARMA HEMATOCRITO. Resul: 34.4 Unid: % Refe: 34.1-44.9   VOLUMEN CORPUSCULAR MEDIO Resul: 78.5 Unid: fL Refe: 79.4-94.8  ALARMA MCH Resul: 25.3 Unid: pg Refe: 25.6-32  ALARMA MCHC Resul: 32.3 Unid: g/dl Refe: 32.2-35.5   PLAQUETAS AUTOMATIZADO O FLUORESCENTES Resul: 262 Unid: 10^3/uL Refe: 182-369   RDW SD Resul: 40.4 Unid: fL Refe: 36.4-46.3   RDW CV Resul: 14.3 Unid: % Refe: 11.7-14.4   MPV Resul: 10.4 Unid: fL Refe: 9.4-12.3   OBSERVACIONES Resul: .     NORMOBLASTOS # Resul: 0.00 Unid: 10^3/uL Refe: 0-0.01   NORMOBLASTOS % Resul: 0.0     GRANULOCITOS INMADUROS % Resul: 0.8 Unid: %    GRANULOCITOS INMADUROS # Resul: 0.09 Unid: 10^3/uL    
                   132133;5/04/2021;RECUENTO LEUCOCITOS Resul: 7.70 Unid: 10^3/uL Refe: 4.5-13.5   NEUTROFILOS Resul: 3.16 Unid: 10^3/uL Refe: 1.56-6.13   LINFOCITOS. Resul: 3.78 Unid: 10^3/uL Refe: 1.18-3.74  ALARMA MONOCITOS. Resul: 0.51 Unid: 10^3/uL Refe: 0.24-0.36  ALARMA EOSINOFILOS Resul: 0.22 Unid: 10^3/uL Refe: 0.04-0.36   BASOFILOS. Resul: 0.02 Unid: 10^3/uL Refe: 0.01-0.08   NEUTROFILOS %. Resul: 41.0 Unid: % Refe: 34-71.1   LINFOCITOS %. Resul: 49.1 Unid: % Refe: 19.3-51.7   MONOCITOS %. Resul: 6.6 Unid: % Refe: 4.7-12.5   EOSINOFILOS %. Resul: 2.9 Unid: % Refe: 0.7-5.8   BASOFILOS% Resul: 0.3 Unid: % Refe: 0.1-1.2   RECUENTO TOTAL DE GLOBULOS ROJOS Resul: 4.71 Unid: 10^6/uL    HEMOGLOBINA Resul: 14.2 Unid: g/dl    HEMATOCRITO. Resul: 40.6 Unid: % Refe: 34.1-44.9   VOLUMEN CORPUSCULAR MEDIO Resul: 86.2 Unid: fL Refe: 79.4-94.8   MCH Resul: 30.1 Unid: pg    MCHC Resul: 35.0 Unid: g/dl    ALERTA PLAQUETAS AUTOMATIZADO O FLUORESCENTES Resul: 245 Unid: 10^3/uL    RDW SD Resul: 36.1 Unid: fL    RDW CV Resul: 11.5 Unid: %    MPV Resul: 9.8 Unid: fL    OBSERVACIONES Resul: .     NORMOBLASTOS # Resul: 0.00 Unid: 10^3/uL    ALERTA NORMOBLASTOS % Resul: 0.0     GRANULOCITOS INMADUROS % Resul: 0.1 Unid: %    ALERTA GRANULOCITOS INMADUROS # Resul: 0.01 Unid: 10^3/uL    
                   44468435;1/04/2021;ALERTA RECUENTO LEUCOCITOS Resul: 10.66 Unid: 10^3/uL Refe: 4.5-13.5   ALERTA NEUTROFILOS Resul: 9.19 Unid: 10^3/uL Refe: 1.56-6.13  ALERTA ALARMA LINFOCITOS. Resul: 0.81 Unid: 10^3/uL Refe: 1.18-3.74  ALERTA ALARMA MONOCITOS. Resul: 0.62 Unid: 10^3/uL Refe: 0.24-0.36  ALERTA ALARMA EOSINOFILOS Resul: 0.00 Unid: 10^3/uL Refe: 0.04-0.36  ALERTA ALARMA BASOFILOS. Resul: 0.02 Unid: 10^3/uL Refe: 0.01-0.08   NEUTROFILOS %. Resul: 86.2 Unid: % Refe: 34-71.1  ALARMA LINFOCITOS %. Resul: 7.6 Unid: % Refe: 19.3-51.7  ALARMA MONOCITOS %. Resul: 5.8 Unid: % Refe: 4.7-12.5   EOSINOFILOS %. Resul: 0.0 Unid: % Refe: 0.7-5.8  ALARMA BASOFILOS% Resul: 0.2 Unid: % Refe: 0.1-1.2   RECUENTO TOTAL DE GLOBULOS ROJOS Resul: 4.70 Unid: 10^6/uL    HEMOGLOBINA Resul: 13.5 Unid: g/dl    HEMATOCRITO. Resul: 39.3 Unid: % Refe: 34.1-44.9   VOLUMEN CORPUSCULAR MEDIO Resul: 83.6 Unid: fL Refe: 79.4-94.8   MCH Resul: 28.7 Unid: pg    MCHC Resul: 34.4 Unid: g/dl    PLAQUETAS AUTOMATIZADO O FLUORESCENTES Resul: 319 Unid: 10^3/uL    RDW SD Resul: 36.4 Unid: fL    RDW CV Resul: 11.9 Unid: %    MPV Resul: 11.0 Unid: fL    ALERTA OBSERVACIONES Resul: .     NORMOBLASTOS # Resul: 0.00 Unid: 10^3/uL    ALERTA NORMOBLASTOS % Resul: 0.0     ALERTA GRANULOCITOS INMADUROS % Resul: 0.2 Unid: %    ALERTA GRANULOCITOS INMADUROS # Resul: 0.02 Unid: 10^3/uL    
                   """)
df = pd.read_csv(data, sep=";",  engine="python")
df
```

Resultado esperado

```
    ID_PACIENTE FECHA_EXAMEN    RESULTADO
    12311545    20/04/2021  11.1
    132133  5/04/2021   14.2 
    44468435    1/04/2021   13.5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La forma más fácil de lograr eso es usando expresiones regulares, en mi caso utilicé 2, una para obtener el valor solo de la hemoglobina y otra para obtener el número referente a la hemoglobina.

```py
import re

hem = re.compile(r"HEMOGLOBINA Resul:s{,} \d+\.\d+") #obtenemos la info de la hemoglobina
num = re.compile(r"HEMOGLOBINA Resul:s{,}") #nos va servir para separar

#buscamos y obtenemos el resultado a ese resultado le quitamos el texto
df["resultado"] = df["RESULTADO"].apply(lambda x: num.split(hem.findall(x)[0])[-1])
df
```

Primero buscamos con la primera expresión regular, eso nos devuelve una lista pero solo necesitamos el primer elemento, y teniendo un resultado como `HEMOGLOBINA Resul: 13.5` así que usamos la otra expresión regular para quitar el texto. Creo que se puede con una sola expresión regular pero no me llevo bien con ellas >_<

Comment: excelente muchas gracias